# How to use proguard.config setting in project.properties file?

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard

I use eclipse and I guess ant building system. In my project root i have a project.properties file which contains proguard.config setting. This setting is said in sdk examples to either

> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

or

> proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt

I have found somewhere that you can state multiple files delimited by colon ":".

But nowhere it is explained in depth which of files takes precedence. I mean does this use file proguard-android.txt from {sdk.dir} folder or proguard-project.txt from project root folder or does it somehow merge the setting from the two.
What is the correct usage? Should I reference both files: the one in {sdk.dir} folder as a default and my proguard-project.txt for project specific stuff? Or should I take proguard-android.txt or proguard-android-optimize.txt and use that as a base for my proguard-project.txt and modify accordingly?
Basically, what is the correct usage or best practice? Experimenting and testing is a bit time consuming to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

In lack of better answer....

Via a completely unrelated google search I found by coincidence this:

http://tools.android.com/recent/proguardimprovements

> As of ADT 17, the proguard.config property refers to a path instead,
>   so you can specify as many configuration files as you want. These are
>   all joined together by ProGuard.

...

> Note that ProGuard typically doesn't let you subtract flags, so if you
>   disagree with one of the default flags, you'll need to copy the global
>   configuration into your own files and remove the lines you want to
>   disable. One such flag you might want to consider is the -dontoptimize

Still very vague.

> flag.